# Ignite Scan Query Throws class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException

Tags: java, ignite

Following Ignite Readme page https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#section-scan-queries I am trying to run the discussed example code.

```
IgniteCache<Long, Person> cache = ignite.cache("mycache");

// Find only persons earning more than 1,000.
try (QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Long, Person>> cursor =
         cache.query(new ScanQuery<Long, Person>((k, p) -> p.getSalary() > 1000))) {
    for (Cache.Entry<Long, Person> entry : cursor)
        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: examples.model.Person
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:707)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1757)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1716)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:798)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:177)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:39)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.advance(GridCacheQueryManager.java:3063)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.onHasNext(GridCacheQueryManager.java:2965)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:53)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:45)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.runQuery(GridCacheQueryManager.java:1141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.processQueryRequest(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1056)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:581)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:380)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1569)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1197)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1093)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: examples.model.Person
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8771)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:349)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:698)
```

The Person object is taken from the Ingnite example (as well as most of the code, available https://gist.github.com/alexterman/075d7e12f470ce873f99d59478260250 on github ). I am running it on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you do not have Person class in classpath of your server node(s).

Ignite will not peer class load its Key-Value classes so you need to distribute them to all nodes before running any distributed operations which use those types.

Alternatively you can use withKeepBinary(), work on BinaryObject's. Something along the lines of

```
cache.withKeepBinary().query(new ScanQuery<Long, BinaryObject>(
    (k, p) -> p.<Integer>getField("salary") > 1000))
```

Comment: Ignite will not peer class load its Key-Value classes so you need to distribute them to all nodes before running any distributed operations which use those types. @alamar how to achieve using this way, can you give some example or more details